# looping through dataframes using 'for'

Tags: r, loops

Here is a simple made up data set:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3),
            y = c(4,6,8),
            z= c(1, 6, 7))

df2 <- data.frame(x = c(3,5,6),
              y = c(3,4,9),
              z= c(6, 7, 7))
```

What I want to do is to create a new variable "a" which is just the sum of all three variables (x,y,z)

Instead of doing this separately for each dataframe I thought it would be more efficient to just create a loop. So here is the code I wrote:

```
my.list<- list(df1, df2)

for (i in 1:2) {
my.list[i]$a<- my.list[i]$x +my.list[i]$y + my.list[i]$z

}
```

or alternatively

```
for (i in 1:2) {
my.list[i]<- transform(my.list[i], a= x+ y+ z)

}
```

In both cases it does not work and the error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" is returned.

What would be the best solution to writing a loop code where I can loop through dataframes?

Comment: you need to use `[[`

Comment: ... so `my.list[[i]]` instead of `my.list[i]`

Comment: If you're concerned about efficiency, combine those data frames into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

See `?Extract`:

> #### Recursive (list-like) objects
>
> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the
>   specified element(s).
>
> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list.

In short, `my.list[i]` returns a list of length 1, and you are trying to assign it a data.frame, so that doesn't work; whereas `my.list[[i]]` returns the data.frame #i in your list, which you can replace with a data.frame.

So you can use either:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  my.list[[i]]$a<- my.list[[i]]$x +my.list[[i]]$y + my.list[[i]]$z

}
```

or

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  my.list[[i]]<- transform(my.list[[i]], a= x+ y+ z)

}
```

But it would be even simpler to use `lapply`, where you don't need `[[`:

```
my.list <- lapply(my.list, function(df) df$a <- df$x + df$y + df$z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an explicit loop to extract the data.frames from the list, just use `lapply`. It takes a list of data.frames (or any object) and a function,  applies the function to every element of the list, and returns a list with the results.

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(4,6,8), z = c(1, 6, 7))
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(3,5,6), y = c(3,4,9), z = c(6, 7, 7))

# Put them in a list
df_list <- list(df1, df2)

# Use lapply to iterate. FUN takes the function you want, and
# then its arguments (a = x + y + z) are just listed after it.
result_list <- lapply(df_list, FUN = transform, a = x + y + z)
```